# Android OpenGL ES Why JPG texture displays wrongly on some devices?

Tags: android, opengl-es, png, textures, jpeg

I'm completely new to OpenGl so be kind.
In my application I'm using JPG and PNG textures. On HTC Desire (android 2.2) or Xperia x8 (android 2.1) everything displays fine, here's the screen: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/xperia.png/). But on newer devices such as Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (android 3.2) or Samsung Galaxy S3 (android 4.x) JPG textures are separated by color? and shifted: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/samsungbs.png/ . Still, PNGs always display ok.

I'm using GLSurfaceView for drawing. And my code responsible for making texture looks like this:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        if (bitmaps[i].hasAlpha()) {
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, bitmaps[i], 0);
        } else {
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, bitmaps[i], 0);
        }
```

By "bitmaps[i].hasAlpha()" I'm trying to differentiate whether the given bitmap is jpg or png. Where can I be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the alpha check and use RGBA for both?

Comment: @Aetherna could you please upload your example images again? the links are dead. I have probably a similar issue and it would be great if I could verify by checking your images. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing these are not power-of-2 textures? If so, maybe the devices it's not working on don't handle non-power-of-2 textures. There is definitely an alignment/pitch thing going on here.

Comment: @Geobits : when I remove alpha check nothing happens. This alpha is a result of a previous fights with proper color display :(.

Jim Buck : Textures are square, power of two and either stored in nodpi folder or loaded with "noScaling" option.

Comment: This does look like an RGBA image that's getting interpreted at an RGB image. The shape in the image is getting "wrapped" by a factor of 1.3333333, which is exactly what an RGBA-as-RGB texel array would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jim Buck.
Just as yousaid. On some devices jpg must be interpreted wrongly and falls into "no alpha if" yet being an RGBA format .
This if statment is unnecessary and it's better to use basic texImage2D method:

```
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmaps[i], 0);
```

On my previous ogl configurations though, it happened that texture's colors where displayed wrongly. So below is my configuration that works good on all of my devices.

```
    private void configureGL(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0.0f, BASE_SCREEN_WIDTH, 0.0f, BASE_SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        //that's a temporal hack below for removing white borders around textures (not a good practice :P)
        gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER, 0.4f); 
    }
```

For ppl with similar problems:

Before, I was using my own drawing thread and building configuration from scratch. This caused weird colors on some devices and made me use this "if aplha" statement. Now, I used GLSurfaceView with implemented Renderer (sample taken from " Android Wireless Application Developement, Second Edition") and basic texImage2D works like a charm.